# Prince of Persia Classic iOS Hidden achievement

Tags: achievements, prince-of-persia

I have gotten 17 of the 18 game center achievements in Prince of Persia Classic HD on my iPad. The last achievement is hidden, and I have searched the Internet on how to unlock it, to no avail. Does someone know how to unlock this last achievement?

Comment: It is the only hidden one.

Comment: You're right. There is literally no source or reference of the 18th achievement on the internet. Like, at all. Weird.

Comment: I always thought that there were only 12 achievements but I don't have the game on IOS so... Could you tell us the achievements you have unlocked so far?

Comment: I have Tools and Trades, Eternal Prison, Inner Reflections, The Path Forward, Flying Might, Of Princes and Mice, Up is Down is Up, Fateful Synapse, Of Love and Revenge, Quest for Immortality, Rescue Race, Sands of Fate, The True Prince, Unstoppable, Peace Maker, Unleashed Wrath, and Slice of Life. The last achievement is hidden. It is the only hidden achievement. I don't even know if anyone has gotten this achievement.

Comment: Could it be that you must play another prince of persia game, or sign up with ubisoft for something?

Comment: My curiosity about the correct answer to this is going to force me to buy this game.  :-D

Answer (score 1):

The pc version of the game has 20 achievements and one of them requires resetting the game and make in record time. Try this.

Answer (score -7):

> 1)The unlocking of this achievement felt most like doing a speed run
>   my old Prince of Persia: Shadow and the Flame.
>
> 2) I prefer using joystick controls over gesture controls as it gives
>   you more control of the Prince. This is required to accomplish this,
>   but I guess some fans will be able to use the gesture controls to do
>   this as well.
>
> 3)Use the your jump button a lot to cut down the number of seconds.
>
> As the levels starts (you have to be really quick): As soon as levels
>   loads (after the load screen)  1) Start running right. Jump once. Then
>   climb up. 2) Don't climb up to next ledge. Instead, run and jump to
>   the ledges to the right. 3) Climb up and then run and then jump to the
>   next set of ledges (will be a bit below). 4) Then Jump before you hit
>   the wall so that you can then quickly climb up. Then run and climb up
>   again. Then climb up onto the right side. Don't climb to left side. As
>   every second counts. 5) You will see the blue flame on your left side.
>   Now do a running jump to There won't be a platform, but it will fly
>   in. Climb yourself up. 6) Then do a running jump so that you can
>   quickly press up to climb up a ledge. (you will be facing the right
>   side) 7) press up again to climb up ledge. (You will face left side)
>   8) Do a running jump from a single ledge towards your left 9) The
>   running jump will allow you to climb up onto the ledge on top that
>   will fly in. 10) Then do a back flip jump to the ledge on the right
>   side. 11) Run a bit to quickly then climb up up a ledge that will fly
>   in 12) Then two ledges will fly in. Jump up and climb it.  13)Do a
>   back flip jump to the ledges on the right.  14) This last part is
>   tricky so jumping at the critical stage will shim off 2 seconds to
>   achieve it in 38 seconds. 15) Do a running jump to the next set of
>   ledges on your left. 16) Then do a quick jump so that you land
>   perfectly next to edge to end of the ledges. 17) Quickly pull yourself
>   down and swing yourself towards right and press the crouch button to
>   hit the flame.
>
> If you do it correctly then you will have unlocked Power Nap
>   Achievement in 38 seconds.

http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/786362-Prince-of-Persia-Shadow-and-the-Flame-iOS-Android-Power-Nap-Achievement-Guide-Forums

Comment: I believe this question is about Prince of Persia Classic HD, whereas your answer is about Prince of Persia: Shadow and the Flame.